# django-background-tasks をGAE（Google App Engine）で動かす

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

時間のかかる処理をdjango-background-tasksを使って非同期化しています。
ローカル上では2つのターミナル上でそれぞれ

> Terminal-A
> python manage.py

> Terminal-B
> python manage.py process_tasks

としてbackground用プロセスを起動しているのですが、GAEで上記2つのプロセスを同時に動かすことができていません。
そもそもGAEではbackgroundのプロセスを動かすことは可能なのか、可能でしたらその設定方法を教えてください。app.yaml等でしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

djangoのbackground taskを使うのではなく、[Cloud Task](https://cloud.google.com/tasks)という別のサービスがあるので、それを使うのがシンプルな解決策だと思います。

Google App EngineはフルマネージドなサービスなのでGoogle App Engineのスタンダード環境では自分で別プロセスを起動しておくことができないと思います。
（フレキシブル環境なら可能かもしれませんがあまり良い方法ではないと思います）

Comment: ありがとうございます！GAE環境（standard）だと不可なのですね。早速Cloud Taskで実装、タスク、キューの挿入を確認しました。